# GTK2 applications broken after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, gtk, gtk-2

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 the rendering of GTK2 applications (e.g. GIMP & Chromium) is totally broken. GTK3 applications on the other hand are working fine.
This is `gtk-demo`from `gtk2.0-examples`:
[image]
The broken rendering is obvious.

The GTK3 demo `gtk3-widget-factory` from `gtk-3-examples` renders totally fine.
So I'm pretty sure this is some issue with GTK2 in specific.

Disabling gnome extensions and switching to the standard theme did not help fixing the issue.

Any ideas how to fix or debug the issue?

Edit: This seems to only be an issue on Wayland. When switching back to X11 the issue disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Ubuntu switched to using Wayland due to the upgrade.
It seems like GTK2 does not properly support Wayland.

Switching back to X11 fixed the issue.

Comment: It is either your configuration or the your upgrade process where something went wrong. Gimp and other GTK2 applications normally work fine in Ubuntu 22.04 on Wayland.

Comment: Oh, good to know. Then I misunderstood some sources.
Any idea what might have gone wrong?
(I edited my question, so people are free to give a proper answer)

Comment: @vanadium i thought GIMP went GTK3 recently?  Because GTK2 is more or less a deprecated set of libs

Comment: @ThomasWard The Gimp still gloriously shines in GTK2. What they achieved by now is 32 bit support for image processing, but the transition to GTK3 is for version 3. Obviously, it would be better if they directly transitionned to GTK4 at this stage, but then I think that would delay version 3 for another three to four years.